# Import module in Rails.application initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

How can I benefit from methods defined in a `lib/module` in one of my `config/initializer`?

```rb
lib/my_module
----

module MyModule
   def custom_method
      12
   end
end
```

so that I can use it as follow

```rb
config/initializer/random_initializer
----

# following imports do not seem to work
# include MyModule
# require 'my_module'
 
Rails.application.configure do
    config.blabla = custom_method
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `module_function`

```rb
# lib/my_module
module MyModule
 def x
  0
 end
 module_function :x
end

# config/initializer/random_initializer
require "my_module"
Rails.application.configure do |config|
 config.blabla = MyModule.x
end
```